# Tailwind CSS styles applied locally, but not when deployed

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I built a static landing page and it works as expected locally on my laptop, when launched using live server. I tried deploying it using render.com but none of the Tailwind styles are applied. Also, the images are not loaded at all. I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 5 hours, reading different posts on the possible solution but nothing seems to work. I'm probably making a silly mistake somewhere but I can't find it. Thanks in advance!

[This is the link to the github repo](https://github.com/djolec/Chirp.git)

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./build/*.html'],
  theme: {

    extend: {
      screens: {
        '2xl':'2130px',
        'lg':'1130px',
      },
      colors: {
        'header-hero': '#fbf8f3',
        'blue-section': '#d7f5f5',
        'yellow-section': '#fbf8f3',
        'p-color': '#737373',
        'logo-color': '#3180f5'
      },
      fontFamily: {
      'inter': ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero-mobile': "url('/assets/hero-image-desktop.png')",
        'hero-tablet': "url('/assets/hero-image-tablet.png')"
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "chirp-starter-files",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Codewell's aim is to provide you with real-world design templates that you can use to practice your HTML and CSS projects.",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./build/css/style.css --watch",
    "prettier": "npx prettier --write **/*.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.3"
  }
}
```

This is how I ordered my files:

I've tried changing the path to the `index.html` file inside the Tailwind config file (the content), but nothing seems to work. I always get the same result.

Comment: Can you check the logs on vercel ? To see if there is some warnings or error

Comment: It's possible that your asset path is different on the live server. When you look at the Network tab in your browser's Dev Tools, can you see if your CSS and image files are being loaded correctly and not 404-ing?

Comment: I checked the network tab in the Dev Tools, and you're right, nothing is loading as it's supposed to. The images are 404-ing and I also got this message for the CSS file: Refused to apply style from 'https://clipboard-8lc8.onrender.com/build/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the problem by altering the path to images and the CSS file. I moved all the images to "build" folder, and changed the path from /build/images/ to ./images/. Also, I changed the path to the CSS file from /build/css/style.css to css/style.css. So basically it was just a path issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!